# Cannot be resized image in codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

```
$this->resizing('cat.jpg',127,97); // function call
```

**After I call the resizing function image not resized and also it didn't show any errors.**

```
public function resizing($filename,$width,$height){

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './resources/plugins/image_multi_uploader_files/files/'.$filename;
        $config['new_image'] = './resources/plugins/image_multi_uploader_files/files/tn/'.$filename;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']         = $width;
        $config['height']       = $height;
        var_dump($config);
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

        if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
        {
             echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }
        else{
            echo "Hello";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = '/img/proizvodi/'.$filename;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = 75;
        $config['height'] = 50; 
        $this->image_lib->clear();
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

 if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()){
  echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
 }
```